# Replacing a new line with its html equivalent in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, line-breaks

I am facing a bit of a quandary, I need to replace a new line with `<br />`. Now, clearly, replacing all instances of \n did not work, as the page did not have proper linebreaks. Here is an example of some possible text:

```
Some text


More text
```

Now, this is an issue because there is no \n and I have no way to auto-insert `<br />`. How can I ensure that this contains proper linebreaks?

This is in PHP. I cannot serve it as plain text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To replace new line breaks with 
 just use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: Jeez, that's so easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want http://php.net/nl2br? Or maybe I have misunderstood...

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use [`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/nl2br).

Your text has to have a newline (`\n`) or carriage return (`\r`) if the text is on 2 different lines.

`nl2br` will handle either case.

Answer (score 2):

php has a built in function for that.

nl2br() i believe.